# Como separar as sílabas das palavras cantaríeis e cantáreis?

Tags: acentuação, divisão-silábica

Estou com essa dúvida sobre a separação silábica dessas duas palavras, porque quero saber em que regra ambas são acentuadas.

```
can-ta-rí-eis (modo indicativo futuro do pretérito)  

can-tá-reis   (modo indicativo pretérito mais-que-perfeito)
```

As separações acimas estão corretas?
Quais as regras de acentuação de ambas as palavras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, estão corretas. A regra que determina a acentuação gráfica na escrita é a Base IX, 2º b) do AO1990:

> Recebem [...] acento agudo:
>   As palavras paroxítonas que apresentam na sílaba tónica/tônica as vogais
>   abertas grafadas a, e, o e ainda i ou u e **que terminam em** -ã(s), -ão(s), -**ei(s)**, -i(s), -um, -uns, ou -us: órfã (pl. órfãs), acórdão (pl. acórdãos), órfão (pl. órfãos), órgão (pl. órgãos), sótão (pl. sótãos); hóquei, jóquei (pl. jóqueis), amáveis (pl. de amável), fáceis (pl. de fácil), fósseis (pl. de fóssil), **amáreis (de amar)**, amáveis (id.), **cantaríeis (de cantar)**, fizéreis (de fazer), fizésseis (id.); beribéri (pl. beribéris), bílis (sg. e pl.), íris (sg. e pl.), júri (pl. júris), oásis (sg. e pl.); álbum (pl. álbuns), fórum (pl. fóruns); húmus (sg. e pl.), vírus (sg. e pl.).

Sem o acento grave, **cantareis** (futuro simples) e **cantáreis** (mais-que-perfeito simples) grafar-se-iam da mesma maneira.

Comment: muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento, se achou minha pergunta plausível por favor dê um voto positivo.